# Unhandled win32 Exception in a C application

Tags: c, exception

I have an application developed using visual studio 2010 under C.
When I run my application,everything appears fine until it arrives to :

```
while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result))) {
    t[k] = atof(row[num_fields - 1]);
    k++;
}
```

The select query doesn't have any problem. An exception message appears:

> An unhandled win32 exception has occurred in ...

I read some articles which tell that this is a problem of deallocating the memory.

I have added:

```
mysql_free_result(result);

free(t);
```

But nothing changed. Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Run the program in a debugger and see where the exception is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, better you can do is running with a debugger.
Once that was said, I can see some things which can produce an exception:

- What happens if `num_fields==0`? You'd get an exception in `row` array
- Check that row is correctly set by `mysql_fetch_row` before executing `atof`. For example, I would separate the same code in several rows with some checks.